# change yii2 kartik fileInput language not working

Tags: yii2, widget, kartik-v

I have a problem with kartik's FileInput widget.
I want to change the language but it's not working here is my code

```
<?php
use kartik\file\FileInput;

    echo $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
        'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['upload-images']),
            'language' => substr(\Yii::$app->language, 0, 2),
        ]
    ]);
```

the language is set to "fr-FR" but I'm still getting texts in english
why? what did I miss?
thank you

Comment: language can be set as a pluginOptions or a widget property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well then I found the solution, it's kind of tricky though
```php

```
<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*'],
    'language' => 'fr',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['upload-images']),
        'language' => substr(\Yii::$app->language, 0, 2),
        'browseLabel' => Yii::t('app', 'Sélectionnez'),
        'dropZoneTitle' => Yii::t('app', 'Glissez et déposez les fichiers ici...')
    ]
]);
?>
```

```